# How to combine two SVG paths together (without spaces)

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I was able to merge two separate paths together [using this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892549/is-there-a-way-to-merge-two-path-elements-svg-using-javascript). However, my animation is still treating this as two separate paths.

Is there a way to combine these two paths without using spaces?

```
M3322.09,361.23V473.45c0,14,2,23.41,23.41,23.41H3809.63 
M3809.63,496.31c21.41,0,166.41-1,166.41-1s13.07.87,82.08.87c31.75,0,63.51-36.21,95.26-75.31"/>
```

```css
svg {
  fill: none;
}

path {
  stroke: tomato;
  stroke-width: 100;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 25 14905 623">
 <path d="M3322.09,361.23V473.45c0,14,2,23.41,23.41,23.41H3809.63 M3809.63,496.31c21.41,0,166.41-1,166.41-1s13.07.87,82.08.87c31.75,0,63.51-36.21,95.26-75.31"/>
</svg>
```

The originally separate paths can be viewable here:

```css
svg {
  fill: none;
}

path {
  stroke: tomato;
  stroke-width: 100;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 25 14905 623">
 <path d="M3322.09,361.23V473.45c0,14,2,23.41,23.41,23.41H3511.9" />
 <path d="M3809.63,496.31c21.41,0,166.41-1,166.41-1s13.07.87,82.08.87c31.75,0,63.51-36.21,95.26-75.31" />
</svg>
```

**The goal is to merge these paths to match the above svg snippet -- without using spaces in the path.**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found an awesome online editor for path manipulations:
[yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/](http://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/)

1. Paste your path segments
2. [optional] Check parsed path commands (e.g. Remove the `M` between segments)
3. [optional] Convert to either 'abs' or 'rel' commands
4. [optional] Set 'minify output' checkbox
5. Copy output

   ```
   m3322.09 361.23v112.22c0 14 2 23.41 23.41 23.41h464.13c21.41 0 166.41-1 166.41-1s13.07.87 82.08.87c31.75 0 63.51-36.21 95.26-75.31
   ```

---

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I found the easiest solution was:

1. Open the SVG file in Inkscape (Free software, cross platform https://inkscape.org)
2. Select the paths to merge
3. From the Path menu, choose Union
4. Save the file

Comment: Add one more step after 1), make sure to convert all strokes into paths so it can be merged: Select Path menu -> Stroke to Path

Comment: a 136MB download, an installation process, and a start up splash and loading, all just to merge paths was more tedious than I'd like it to be, BUT, I still haven't found a simpler tool than this once you get into the program. Thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

The answer is

`M3322.09,361.23V473.45c0,14,2,23.41,23.41,23.41H3809.63 c21.41,0,166.41-1,166.41-1s13.07.87,82.08.87c31.75,0,63.51-36.21,95.26-75.31`

`H3511.9` means draw a horizontal line until x point at 3511.9 (with whatever y was previously inherited)

`M3809.63,496.31` means move the "cursor" to an x, y coordinate.

I changed `H3511.9` to `H3809.63` and removed `M3809.63,496.31` and continued with `c21.41...` which is a draw curve command.

These resources helped me to understand the draw commands for the `d` `path` attribute.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6TWzfLGAKo

Answer (score 2):

For those who came upon this question while researching to make sure there would be no problems from merging paths like I was, the problem here is just a typo.

In the above merged snippet, the ending of the first path was changed from its original `23.41H3511.9` to `23.41H3809.63`.

Putting paths together by putting a space (or no space at all, just don't have a comma between the paths when placing them in the d attribute value) should always work without modification.

(On a side note, Raphael's answer made SVGs a lot less cryptic to me now after reading his links and tips)